# How to compile Zoneminder source files

Tags: bash, perl, zoneminder

I'm trying to make a video surveillance system with my Raspberry Pi (running raspbian) using `Zoneminder`.

Default action of `Zoneminder` is only to send an e-mail but I want also to run a script which tells Raspberry how to react in case of alarm.

I found two ways to do that:

1. Modify `zmfilters.pl` file generating a bash command when there is a not archived event having an alarm image
2. Modify `zm_monitor.cpp` file making it write a bash when current state go to alarm.
   In the first solution i don't know how to tell in perl language to system to make a bash and in the second one i'm not capable of compile `Zoneminder` once the file is modified.
   The second solution is more efficient but I'm new in linux and I cannot understand how to compile it.

I followed this [guide](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_11.10_64-bit_with_ZoneMinder_1.25.0_from_source) for Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you let us know which step of the guide failed and what was the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I used zoneminder several years ago. I may be wrong, but it seemed like a dead project.
a simple alternative with active support which I know works quite well on a raspberry pi is "[motion](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera/step7/Installing-the-motion-detection-software/)".

Comment: It doesnot seems a dead project, the last commit https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/commits/master was done 2 days ago.

Comment: It may as well be dead. http://shinobi.video/articles/2017-07-29-why-not-just-use-zoneminder